# How to create a drop-down list using vlookup based on multiple criterias?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, return, vlookup

I am trying to set up a front page to access some data in excel.
The Entry data sheet has 5 columns. "Regions" ; "Product code" ; "Categories" ; "Permittance" ; "Comments".

The "Region" and "Product code" is a unique drop down list. 
Then I would like the Categories to be a drop down list returning the categories related to e.g. USA and 123.

I've created an example file, but the original data has over 8000 rows and 350 unique product codes.

I have already created unique dynamic dropdown lists for Regions and product codes.

I thought about dependent drop down lists. But since the amount of data is so big, i gave up on it.

Then i have used Vlookup, but that only returns the first instance of the combination.
The Vlookup function used so far is given below:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2;tblData;4;FALSE)
```

---

Data sheet:

[image]

---

Data entry sheet:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some mock-data to support your post, as well as further describing the source data and the desired outcome.

Comment: Note that `vlookup()` and `index/match` will provide the first instance of a match within a lookup range, so depending on desire, you may want to have slicers/filters based on your entries to help narrow down a table with all information.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for the quick answer. A link at the top has been added. 
It's my first time posting on stackoverflow, so I am sorry for the missing information.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, posting something for people to download is frowned upon.  Please include only images and text into your post.

Comment: Okay bad start from my behalf :(  But I am not allowed to embed pictures yet because I am a new user. Thanks for the advice though. I will try to figure it out in another way.

Comment: If you can post a link to the image I can try and edit your post to embed the image after.  Also, please remove the link for the download of your file.

Comment: [Data Sheet](https://i.imgur.com/n3ej8Pt.jpg)
[Entry data sheet](https://i.imgur.com/sWefY3h.jpg)

Comment: Added your images to the post